# how to use wildcard (*) for join parameter in KQL?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, azure-log-analytics, kql, azure-sentinel

I'm racking my brain with this and would like some help. :)

I want to know how to use wildcard(*) for join union parameter.

I need to join two tables with the same names in the fields, however, some fields may come with the wildcard(*), since for this field I want all to be validated.

**My exceptions table:**

```
let table_excep=  datatable (Computer:string,Event_id:string, logon_type:string) 
[
"Pc_01","*","4", 
"Pc_02","4648","*", 
"*","*","60" 
];
```

**My data table:**

```
let table_windows=  datatable (Computer:string,Event_id:string, logon_type:string)
[ 
"Pc_01","5059","4",
"Pc_02","4648","1",
"Pc_03","61","60"
];
```

When running, it doesn't bring anything in the result.

For this union, I want the 3 union fields to be considered, ie based on the exceptions table, if computer_name is Pc_01 and logon_type is 4, no matter what event_id is, this log should be displayed, since the field of eventi_id in the exception list is wildcard(*).

I'm not finding a way to solve this problem since the join condition only allows "==" and "and".

Comment: pasting the definitions of the datatables will make it much easier to understand and answer the question

Comment: Hi Avnera. Thanks for the suggestion. I just edited the text to make the tabala content clearer.

Comment: `\*` is not valid. Should be `*` or `\\*`

Answer (score 0):

cross join (inner join on 1=1) + where

```
let table_excep=  datatable (Computer:string,Event_id:string, logon_type:string) 
[
"Pc_01","*","4", 
"Pc_02","4648","*", 
"*","*","60" 
];
let table_windows=  datatable (Computer:string,Event_id:string, logon_type:string)
[ 
"Pc_01","5059","4",
"Pc_02","4648","1",
"Pc_03","61","60"
]; 
table_excep | extend dummy = 1 
| join kind=inner (table_windows | extend dummy = 1) on dummy 
| where     (Computer == Computer1 or Computer == '*') 
        and (Event_id == Event_id1 or Event_id == '*')
        and (logon_type == logon_type1 or logon_type == '*')
```

| Computer | Event_id | logon_type | dummy | Computer1 | Event_id1 | logon_type1 | dummy1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pc_01 | * | 4 | 1 | Pc_01 | 5059 | 4 | 1 |
| Pc_02 | 4648 | * | 1 | Pc_02 | 4648 | 1 | 1 |
| * | * | 60 | 1 | Pc_03 | 61 | 60 | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA6WQQWuDQBCF74L/4eElRjxom4SmxVPpvfdSxGaHdBvdFbOpCeTHd0dXY9rcurCw89684dspycAUHyXldNxQnQGiMEWnIHzWVX0w1DzuTSPVNn75JmVyKYYapd5qlZtTTU6aw/fefC943eRJGsRBZO8iiOGkOy5Xi4feYTVyTasksOX7k%20%20VI1ErldDt/t9MFgkTpmWyXPdYf6nSUbxnqLQnYzA7YbInnEFHQ0pAHKrqhAypbTjjS0uFneXOpFLUILz6yY3UHFq5ivPtJzUEPuNHkWUY3il0g6kxi2a8crhT2NHhsBH2h3cXnBoc/JW7LI4bLlWXvTY5/QOHY1BHOgIAAA==)